# change css of asp:AutoCompleteExtender from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to know how to change `CompletionListItemCssClass` for a asp:AutoCompleteExtender in javascript because I need to chnage it every time I change index of my combobox
this is my code:
ajaxtoolki:

```
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="autocom" ClientIDMode="Static"  runat="server" CompletionSetCount="10"   CompletionListItemCssClass="toolkitEnglish" 
        EnableCaching="true" MinimumPrefixLength="1" TargetControlID="txtBoxWord"   ServicePath="~/translator/AutoComplete.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"  ></asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

I tried this but it does not work:

```
document.getElementById('autocom').CompletionListItemCssClass = "toolkitEnglish";
```

Answer (score 0):

`CompletionListItemCssClass` is a server side property name; that won't work in JavaScript.

But if the auto-complete extender renders an element with an id of `autocom` that you need to set the css class on, then this should work

```
document.getElementById('autocom').className = "toolkitEnglish";
```